# SML in org-mode block returns it = "stdIn" : string

Tags: emacs, org-mode, sml

When I start an SML REPL and put in

```
print("floor is : " ^ (Int.toString (floor 3.1823)) ^ "\n");
```

I get

```
floor is : 3
val it = () : unit
```

i.e., expected behavior. But when I do the same thing in an Emacs org-mode source block:

```
#+name: sml_test
#+begin_src sml :exports both
print("floor is : " ^ (Int.toString (floor 3.1823)) ^ "\n");
#+end_src
```

I get the cryptic (for me)

```
#+RESULTS: sml_test
: val it = "stdIn" : string
```

Does anyone from the ML world know what this could mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is probably a bug in ob-sml. If you visit the *sml* buffer, and do C-c C-c on the source block, the sml REPL gets this input:

```
print("floor is : " ^ (Int.toString (floor 3.1823)) ^ "\n");
; "stdIn";
```

Note the extra "stdIn" there. Also if you set `:results output` on the block, you should get the standard output of the block, but I get the same thing as with the default `:results value` setting (and the same thing you get: the cryptic thing which I guess is the result of that spurious "stdIn" - I should say that I know nothing about ML, so take all this with the appropriately sized grain of salt). I would open an issue on the ob-sml github project.

Comment: I did it. Thanks.

Comment: I don't want to dash your hopes, but I just noticed that ob-sml seems to have been stagnant for three years. If you don't get any response, maybe you could fork the project and do some fixing?